# User.Identity.Name is empty on Safari browsers

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, safari

Good morning. we currently have a MVC 5 application on asp.net 4.5.1, that we are aiming to be used on the mobile browsers.

we are using some ajax calls to fill some drop downs on the View, however since those API calls are using the logged on user, the server is rejecting the call from safari.
This is evident on iphone safari, but not on iphone chrome.
The controller side looks like this

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("API/Account/Dependents/{idPlusType}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetUserOrDependantInfo(string idPlusType)
{
    ...
    string loggedOnUser = User.Identity.Name;
}
```

It is this part what is coming back as string.empty

my client side is a simple ajax to a .get

```
$.ajax({
    url: path,
    dataType: "json",
    type: "GET",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (d) {
    -- Rest
    }
}
```

Now fiddler show very similar request. One the one from chrome is serviced correctly. The one from safari it is not.

Fiddler request for safari from a iphone

```
    Cookie:.ASPXAUTH=0530DF01D09167C311032C3A6A258D24C20A9189FC8ACE76239016815047D4FEB5FCDDAED04E7FBCA41763388B1C655987732203CFD77D4B76C1EC3200ACCC26F61151BA77F4B6C3745C20D1D70369677814BB2A;__RequestVerificationToken_L2V6VmVyaWZ5MTIzTUhB0=Vb_TYkr-Begl4fv4JulkokhM24VFZjXjt_gHdsmz3ckfkKbBJu8YmNJcghafJ8_0Edn0Lb9SopXA7Di4fKZm6uV1AOM1;__RequestVerificationToken_L2V6VmVyaWZ5MTIzTUhBVGVzdA2=_sxROjMA7jW8PbluEKtzEOAbdJfpBDpYRWJLhwR6SDlX10UA7m7FU-6xezerP73HyqeLqrmqdYfwQfLftIhwqr5Fs0w1; ASP.NET_SessionId=dbh0kje3unlap545zeuvld31
```

now Chrome from the same iphone.

```
Cookie:ASP.NET_SessionId=qgbcybtzvw2sxaa3w1yphu1z;__RequestVerificationToken_L2V6VmVyaWZ5MTIzTUhBVGVzdA2=v7ZBYrFtmg1GuuETKlIubWKr7T4Rddt1I40f9i56LzmQDI1svaw6qpk4hpuZqm_12ltrEkak9GewyhXU1rX0gQCiMvg1;__RequestVerificationToken_L2V6VmVyaWZ5MTIzTUhB0=NkM3pLoBJeYd2MTMKXwrh7dFY7uQYLGbzVN9nPy-ai7oNdmPXoxbI8Z6Xc0SGkVS3IxY-gmTTzD6m_eu2tKNjOA46jU1;.ASPXAUTH=2CBEC21CF8A3EDD3A4C6870FF4D68F16536C4CA9D87634CA4EB817589140EC85B8967C8A2F4ACAD8CF52FAAD5E4488F2210C6B75CCF55412CFA6F6ADD66323DB5072CD3622092865B214AE3626EE7A4F6BD8494B
```

Comment: What kind of authentication are you using? Cookie authentication or tokens?

Comment: I don't have an exact answer but Safari is notorious for problems with cookies, so I'd start looking there.

Comment: We are using cookie based authentication. Not token based.

Answer (score 0):

We ended up switching from .ajax to .getJson function and that helped the problem.
We are not sure why, but after that the server side started seeing the user authenticated.